# Django: Update multiple fields at once

Tags: python, django, database

I am fairly new to Django, but it's fun. I built a table with billing information. Let's say I have table structure like this: id, date, price, money received, and so on.

Now, once in a while, I would like to update that table, because everything may have been filled in except for the receipt of the purchase price. Therefore I thought it to be cool to generate a html table with all the entries from the db table in it. Then in the last column there could be input fields so that I could fill in whether there was a payment or not. But I do not want to make separate entries for each bill. Instead it would be cool, just to fill in the last column at once and the just to click a button "update". And then all the fields in the db should get an update about the payment. But generic views like UpdateView seem to only apply to single objects (or data rows if this is a better name for it).

Could you give me an advice how to get such an update table in Django?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can bulk create a lot of object to easily.

```
# many to many example
book1 = Book(name='book1 ')
book2 = Book(name='book2 ')
book3 = Book(name='book3 ')
entry = Entry.objects.get(id=1)
entry.books.add(book1 , book2 , book3 )

# other example
books = []
for i in range(20):
    books.append(Book(name="blog"+str(i), headline='tagline'+str(i)))
Books.objects.bulk_create(books)
```

Comment: Dear Ali. Thanks for your reply. I am afraid that my bad English led to a confusing question. I do not want to create new data rows in my db table. I just have data rows, which include one field that is not filled when the data row (object) is created. Later then I want to fill that field in the db, but not one table row at a time, but multiple at once. And they do not have the same content, but one could be filled with "8.3" and another one with "12.7". Could this clear things up? Thanks again!